# Inheritance and self-recursive type inference

Tags: scala, type-inference, typechecking

(Scala 2.11.8)

I have a trait `GenTableLike` with complex self-recursive type signature which defines method `++` for concatenating compatible table implementations. I also have a hierarchy `GenTableLike >: KeyTable >: MapKeyTable`. However, `++`'ing two `MapKeyTable` fails to infer self-recursive types.

Here's somewhat simplified snippet in which problem still reproduces:

```
trait GenTableLike[RKT,
                   CKT,
                   +A,
                   +SelfType[+A2] <: GenTableLike[RKT, CKT, A2, SelfType, TransposedType],
                   +TransposedType[+A2] <: GenTableLike[CKT, RKT, A2, TransposedType, SelfType]] {
  def ++[B >: A,
         T2 <: GenTableLike[RKT, CKT, B, ST, TT],
         ST[+A2] <: GenTableLike[RKT, CKT, A2, ST, TT],
         TT[+A2] <: GenTableLike[CKT, RKT, A2, TT, ST]](that: T2): SelfType[B] = ???
}

trait KeyTable[RKT, CKT, +A]
  extends GenTableLike[RKT,
                       CKT,
                       A,
                       KeyTable.Curried[RKT, CKT]#Self,
                       KeyTable.Curried[CKT, RKT]#Self]

object KeyTable {
  /** Type helper for defining self-recursive type */
  type Curried[RKT, CKT] = {
    type Self[+A] = KeyTable[RKT, CKT, A]
  }
}

class MapKeyTable[RKT, CKT, +A]
  extends KeyTable[RKT, CKT, A]
  with GenTableLike[RKT,
                    CKT,
                    A,
                    MapKeyTable.Curried[RKT, CKT]#Self,
                    MapKeyTable.Curried[CKT, RKT]#Self]

object MapKeyTable {
  /** Type helper for defining self-recursive type */
  type Curried[RKT, CKT] = {
    type Self[+A] = MapKeyTable[RKT, CKT, A]
  }
}

val t1: MapKeyTable[Int, String, Int] = ???
val t2: MapKeyTable[Int, String, Any] = ???

// The following works
t1.++[Any, MapKeyTable[Int, String, Any], ({ type ST[+A2] = MapKeyTable[Int, String, A2] })#ST, ({ type TT[+A2] = MapKeyTable[String, Int, A2] })#TT](t2)
t1.++[Any, MapKeyTable[Int, String, Any], MapKeyTable.Curried[Int, String]#Self, MapKeyTable.Curried[String, Int]#Self](t2)
// Error: inferred type arguments [Int,MapKeyTable[Int,String,Any],Nothing,Nothing] do not conform to method ++'s type parameter bounds [B >: Int,T2 <: GenTableLike[Int,String,B,ST,TT],ST[+A2] <: GenTableLike[Int,String,A2,ST,TT],TT[+A2] <: GenTableLike[String,Int,A2,TT,ST]]
t1 ++ t2
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

## Notes:

Self-type and transposed type are used to define function return types. I also have an IndexedTable implementation defined as follows, so I can't rework self-type to accept 3 arguments

```
trait IndexedTable[+A]
    extends GenTableLike[Int,
                         Int,
                         A,
                         IndexedTable,
                         IndexedTable]

class IndexedSeqTable[+A]
    extends IndexedTable[A]
    with GenTableLike[Int,
                      Int,
                      A,
                      IndexedSeqTable,
                      IndexedSeqTable]
```

Comment: Maybe one of https://github.com/slamdata/matryoshka https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBmx9NsNSXM&t=1975s https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution to my problem which I think is better than @PH88's proposal. I removed the constraints from `SelfType`/`TransposedType` and used `ST forSome { type ST[+A2] }` syntax in `++` argument type, like in the description of https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8039

Side effects of this solution:

1. Can't define method implementations in `GenTableLike` in terms of other methods (since they will return a `SelfType` of an unknown nature) - i.e. can't reuse methods inside `GenTableLike` code. This can be workarounded by providing additional inheritance layer below `GenTableLike` and above `KeyTable` and `IndexedTable`
2. Subclasses may define non-tables as their self/transposed types, but that doesn't seem like a big issue - there's no reason for them to do so.

Resulting code:

```
trait GenTableLike[RKT,
                   CKT,
                   +A,
                   +SelfType[+A2],
                   +TransposedType[+A2]] {
  def ++[B >: A](that: GenTableLike[RKT,
                                    CKT,
                                    B,
                                    ST forSome { type ST[+A2] },
                                    TT forSome { type TT[+A2] }]): SelfType[B] = ???
}

// Common ancestor for all table classes
trait GenTable[RKT, CKT, +A]
  extends GenTableLike[RKT,
                       CKT,
                       A,
                       GenTable.Curried[RKT, CKT]#Self,
                       GenTable.Curried[CKT, RKT]#Self] {
  // Here we can implement common methods reusing other methods due to proper SelfType bounds
}

object GenTable {
  /** Type helper for defining self-recursive type */
  private type Curried[RKT, CKT] = {
    type Self[+A] = GenTable[RKT, CKT, A]
  }
}

trait KeyTable[RKT, CKT, +A]
  extends GenTable[RKT, CKT, A]
  with GenTableLike[RKT,
                    CKT,
                    A,
                    KeyTable.Curried[RKT, CKT]#Self,
                    KeyTable.Curried[CKT, RKT]#Self]

object KeyTable {
  /** Type helper for defining self-recursive type */
  type Curried[RKT, CKT] = {
    type Self[+A] = KeyTable[RKT, CKT, A]
  }
}

class MapKeyTable[RKT, CKT, +A]
  extends KeyTable[RKT, CKT, A]
  with GenTableLike[RKT,
                    CKT,
                    A,
                    MapKeyTable.Curried[RKT, CKT]#Self,
                    MapKeyTable.Curried[CKT, RKT]#Self] {
  override def ++[B >: A](that: GenTableLike[RKT,
                                             CKT,
                                             B,
                                             ST forSome { type ST[+A2] },
                                             TT forSome { type TT[+A2] }]): MapKeyTable[RKT, CKT, B] = {
    new MapKeyTable
  }
}

object MapKeyTable {
  /** Type helper for defining self-recursive type */
  type Curried[RKT, CKT] = {
    type Self[+A] = MapKeyTable[RKT, CKT, A]
  }
}

trait IndexedTable[+A]
  extends GenTable[Int, Int, A]
  with GenTableLike[Int,
                    Int,
                    A,
                    IndexedTable,
                    IndexedTable]

class IndexedSeqTable[+A]
    extends IndexedTable[A]
    with GenTableLike[Int,
                      Int,
                      A,
                      IndexedSeqTable,
                      IndexedSeqTable] {
  override def ++[B >: A](that: GenTableLike[Int,
                                             Int,
                                             B,
                                             ST forSome { type ST[+A2] },
                                             TT forSome { type TT[+A2] }]): IndexedSeqTable[B] = {
    new IndexedSeqTable
  }
}


// Usage

def s1: IndexedSeqTable[Int] = ???
def s2: IndexedSeqTable[Any] = ???

def t1: MapKeyTable[Int, Int, Int] = ???
def t2: MapKeyTable[Int, Int, Any] = ???

// All of this works with result being of proper type
t1.++[Any](t2)
t1 ++ t2
s1 ++ s2
t1 ++ s1
s1 ++ t1
s2 ++ t1
```

Answer (score 1):

How about turning the `SelfType` and `TransposeType` into abstract types?  This is simpler, and working:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

trait GenTableLike[RKT, CKT, +A] {
  type SelfType[+A2] <: GenTableLike[RKT, CKT, A2]
  type TransposedType[+A2] <: GenTableLike[CKT, RKT, A2]

  def ++[B >: A](that: GenTableLike[RKT, CKT, B]): SelfType[B]
}

trait KeyTable[RKT, CKT, +A]
  extends GenTableLike[RKT, CKT, A] {
  override type SelfType[+A2] <: KeyTable[RKT, CKT, A2]
  override type TransposedType[+A2] <: KeyTable[CKT, RKT, A2]
}

class MapKeyTable[RKT, CKT, +A]
  extends KeyTable[RKT, CKT, A] {
  override type SelfType[+A2] = MapKeyTable[RKT, CKT, A2]
  override type TransposedType[+A2] = MapKeyTable[CKT, RKT, A2]

  override def ++[B >: A](that: GenTableLike[RKT, CKT, B]): MapKeyTable[RKT, CKT, B] =
    new MapKeyTable[RKT, CKT, B]
}

val t1 = new MapKeyTable[Int, String, Int]
val t2 = new MapKeyTable[Int, String, Any]

// The following works
t1.++[Any](t2)
t1 ++ t2


trait IndexedTable[+A]
  extends GenTableLike[Int, Int, A] {
  override type SelfType[+A2] <: IndexedTable[A2]
  override type TransposedType[+A2] <: IndexedTable[A2]
}

class IndexedSeqTable[+A]
  extends IndexedTable[A] {
  override type SelfType[+A2] = IndexedSeqTable[A2]
  override type TransposedType[+A2] = IndexedSeqTable[A2]

  override def ++[B >: A](that: GenTableLike[Int, Int, B]): IndexedSeqTable[B] = new IndexedSeqTable[B]
}
```

***Updated on Feb 15 in response to Alex's comment:***

Recursive type + inheritance is tricky and I always avoid it if possible :-).
If `SelfType` and `TransposeType` are use as function return types only, how about eliminate the `SelfType` and `TransposeType` altogether and use implicit builder like:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

trait GenTableLike[RKT, CKT, +A] {

  def value: A

  def ++[B >: A](that: GenTableLike[RKT, CKT, B])(implicit builder: GenTableLike.Builder[this.type, B]): builder.Self = {
    builder.buildSelf(that.value)
  }

  def transpose(implicit builder: GenTableLike.Builder[this.type, A]) = builder.buildTranspose(value)

}

object GenTableLike {

  trait Builder[-This, -A] {
    type Self
    type Transpose

    def buildSelf(a: A): Self

    def buildTranspose(a: A): Transpose
  }

}

trait KeyTable[RKT, CKT, +A]
  extends GenTableLike[RKT, CKT, A] {
}

class MapKeyTable[RKT, CKT, +A](override val value: A)
  extends KeyTable[RKT, CKT, A] {
}

object MapKeyTable {

  implicit def builder[RKT, CKT, A] = new GenTableLike.Builder[MapKeyTable[RKT, CKT, A], A] {
    override type Self = MapKeyTable[RKT, CKT, A]
    override type Transpose = MapKeyTable[CKT, RKT, A]

    override def buildSelf(a: A): Self = new MapKeyTable[RKT, CKT, A](a)

    override def buildTranspose(a: A): Transpose = new MapKeyTable[CKT, RKT, A](a)
  }

}

class MapKeyTableEx[RKT, CKT, +A](override val value: A)
  extends MapKeyTable[RKT, CKT, A](value)

object MapKeyTableEx {
  implicit def builder[RKT, CKT, A] = new GenTableLike.Builder[MapKeyTableEx[RKT, CKT, A], A] {
    override type Self = MapKeyTableEx[RKT, CKT, A]
    override type Transpose = MapKeyTableEx[CKT, RKT, A]

    override def buildSelf(a: A): Self = new MapKeyTableEx[RKT, CKT, A](a)

    override def buildTranspose(a: A): Transpose = new MapKeyTableEx[CKT, RKT, A](a)
  }

}


val t1 = new MapKeyTable[Int, String, Int](1)
val t2 = new MapKeyTable[Int, String, Any]("b")
val t3 = new MapKeyTableEx[Int, String, Int](1)
val t4 = new MapKeyTableEx[Int, String, Any]("b")

// The following works
t1 ++ t2
t1 ++ t3
t2 ++ t3
t3 ++ t4

t1.transpose
t2.transpose
t3.transpose
t4.transpose
```

Comment: I've tried that, the problem with this approach is that you can't extend `MapKeyTable` and override its `SelfType` - `MapKeyTable` definition for `SelfType` uses `=` and not `<:`. On the other hand, you can't declare `SelfType` using `<:` because it won't allow you to return `MapKeyTable` from `++` (which makes sense - `++` contract will be broken if child class overrides `SelfType` and not `++`)

Comment: (Regarding your second solution) This is one way to solve it, thank you for that. If I get it right, that's sort of thing Scala collections do, but simpler. The problem with this is that we have to standardize what exactly builder should accept in order to build a table, while different implementations might have different opinions on this - forcing them to a single format will lead to ineffective implementations.

Comment: I'm still going to award you the bounty for your efforts though. Thanks!